# I want to copy a directory as it is to another directory including all sub-directories using Python

Tags: python, directory, copy

```
.SomeFolderName/.../../
```

Where ".../../" is a folder that includes lot of directories and files. I want to copy the same folder to another folder using python code. Here I kept the another folder as Output.

```
.Output/SomeFolderName/.../../
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I have no idea about it.